# How to prevent a Nan/V8 thread crashing a node host process?

Tags: node.js, nan, v8

I am building a native node module with Nan/V8 that uses [AsyncWorker](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/main/doc/asyncworker.md#api_nan_async_worker) to create an async function.

Is there a way to protect the node host application from dying if my thread crashes? The data each worker executes is purely local, so the worst case would be a memory leak, but I need to protect the host application from crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crash is generally a per-process event. There is no way to let a single thread crash and have other threads in the same process live on.

FWIW, this is unrelated to Node/Nan/V8. It's one of the key reasons why all modern browsers use multi-*process* architectures.

Of course, switching from a multi-threaded application to a multi-process model comes at a cost: exchanging data with other processes (IPC, "inter-process communication") is generally more cumbersome than coordinating a couple of threads within a single process.

That said, people sometimes use the word "crash" with somewhat different meaning, so it's possible that there are other answers here. E.g. from a JavaScript perspective, an unhandled exception could be described as a "crash" -- and that would be easy to handle and recover from, not even a thread has to die for that.

Also, scenarios where applications actually have to deal with crashing processes are pretty rare (browsers are an example of that); most of the time developers' time is better spent ensuring that no crashes happen, instead of trying to handle them when they do happen. Node itself should be stable enough that it doesn't just crash; and for your own module, designing (and debugging, if needed :-) ) it so it won't crash may be more feasible/effective than devising (and testing) a scheme that lets it gracefully handle crashes.

Comment: Thanks for the input. You can actually prevent that the OS terminates the host application if a thread dies. There are error and crash handlers you can register on Windows, macOS and Linux that make use of  longjump to skip back to a safe haven. You have of course leaking memory but as said a crashing thread doesn't necessarily mean the death of the host app as I have done this myself but its too many years ago and I wasn't sure if there is an abstract way in the Node or NAN world

Comment: @HelloWorld - Yeah, but it means that some portion of the server state is in an indetermined position.  Memory, file handles and other resources may be stranded/leaked and, of course, that thread is in a completely indeterminate state itself.  In some cases, resources that affect other threads (like mutexes or other types of locks) may also be impacted.  Preventing and then restarting if it does happen is the only way to know you can cleanly proceed.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. thanks a lot!